# Unable to Display image in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am unable to display images in pages created using Google App Engine(Python).

My app.yaml file has :

```
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

And the python file has:

```
self.response.out.write("""<img src = '/images/title.gif' />""")
```

The image still does not display in the page.

Thanks

Comment: Does that bit in your app.yaml come after another one that also matches '/images/title.gif', like '.*'?

Comment: yes. it did. But even when i changed the order, it did not work

Answer (score 1):

I would test:

1. Do you see http://yourapp.appspot.com/images/title.gif?
2. Are you sure that images folder is on your app root?
3. Title.gif is a "working" image?

I would recommend you to use a static folder to store your static contents organized in subfolders:

```
Root  
  static  
     images
     stylesheets
     javascripts
  app.yaml
```

and Mapping a url /images like this.

```
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  mime_type: image/png
```

`mime_type: image/png` is optional; if not specified, the MIME type for a file will be derived from the file's filename extension.

Comment: No he doesn't. If he has a directory called 'images' off his app's root dir, what he's listed should work just fine.

Comment: I had the images folder in my root.
Root
  images
  app.yaml

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem. The solution was ultimately very simple. You need to try to reposition the url handler for the static directory before the apphandler for the main.app 
like this:

handlers:

- url: `/favicon\.ico`   static_files: `favicon.ico`   upload: `favicon\.ico`
- url: `/photos`   static_dir: `photos`
- url: `.*`   script: `main.app`

This annoyed me for like 45 min before I found the solution on google.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a directory called 'images' in your app's root directory? What does it contain? What do you get if you attempt to fetch the file directly?

Comment: The images directory is in my root folder. It has the title.gif image. When i run this, the page display but the image doesn't. 
I am also not able to access it directly,as in
http://yourapp.appspot.com/images/title.gif

Comment: If the images directory is in your root directory, then the problem is simple: The path you're specifying in app.yaml is static/images, but it's just in 'images'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be about upper/lower case difference between systems. Windows is not upper/lower sensitive, but Linux is. Supposing your actual file name is Title.GIF. It works if it is written as title.gif on a Windows machine (Your Local machine), but does not work on a Linux server (Google App Server).

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this to happen is if you do not provide space between `- url` and if you do not restart your server. It will show `404` that time. If you restart your server then you will encounter the error in `app.yaml`. This is one very common mistake that people commit. Because the way you have done it seems that it should work fine.